Group ring definition. How to see the equivalence?
I'm an undergraduate studying mathematics, and I'm struggling with the two definitions of group rings. Each definition seems fine on its own, but I don't see how they match up. The first definition I encounter defines $RG$ as a free module with $G$ the set of basis elements and coefficients in $R$. The second definition I see defines $RG$ as a space of functions $G \to R$ with finite support. I'm struggling to see how these two objects are the same.
Wikipedia gives an example. Let $R$ be the complex numbers and $G$ be the cyclic group of order $3$: $\{1_G, a, a^2\}$, where $a^3 = 1_G$. Then using the first definition, an element $r \in RG$ will have the form:
$$
r = z_01_G + z_1a + z_2a^2 
$$
where $z_0, z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.
In what sense can we view this as a map $G \to R$? I can't see it.

The free module approach seems t9 need a bit more to make it a ring.

Try $\phi(g)=z_g.$

The linked duplicate also has another linked duplicate with answers to this in the comments.  It really ought to be another link here but the comment-answer situation botches that, unfortunately.

Formal sums of the form $\sum\limits_{g\in G}\alpha_g g$ (with $\alpha_g\in R$) is how we think of the elements of $RG$, but this is not a rigorous definition. After all, what are "formal sums"? The formal definition is functions $G\to R$ with finite support. The sum I mentioned is the function that maps $g\to\alpha_g$. The formal sum is just a very nice notation that is easy to work with. There is often a difference between formal definition and how we actually think of the elements.
In your example, the map is $1_G\to z_0, a\to z_1, a^2\to z_2$.

So alpha_g g can be identified with a delta function, alpha_g delta_g, where delta_g is the delta function which takes on the value 1 at g and 0 elsewhere in the group?

@JudeHorsley Yes, the element $\alpha_g g$ is the function that maps $g\to\alpha_g$, and maps all other elements to $0$.

Makes sense, thank you!

Hint: Look at $z_01_G + z_1a + z_2a^2$. Stare at it. See if you can find some natural way to use this expression to associate one particular complex number to $1_G$, one particular complex number to $a$, and one particular complex number to $a^2$.
Answer behind spoiler:

 Take the coefficient of the relevant element of $G$.


The two definitions are dual:

For the formal sums definition, $RG$ can be thought of as induced by maps $R \to G$ (this is the free module construction, where the group ring consists of $R$-linear combinations of these maps). By abuse, we often conflate $g \in G$ with
$$
1 \overset{\phi_g}{\longmapsto} G, 
$$
so when we write, e.g., $2g - 3h \in RG$ what we actually mean is the map $2\phi_g - 3\phi_h$, which is defined by
$$
1 \longmapsto 2\phi_g(1) - 3\phi_h(1).
$$
For the space of functions definition, sometimes denoted $R[G]$ to differentiate, we are considering the free $R$-module induced by maps $G \to R$ and linear combinations of such. Again, when we write some linear combination $2g - 3h \in R[G]$ what we actually mean is the map $2\psi_g - 3\psi_h$, which is determined by where it sends group elements:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
g &\longmapsto \phantom{-}2 \\
h &\longmapsto -3 \\
k &\longmapsto \phantom{-}0 \qquad \text{for all } k \notin \{g, h\}
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

These are linear duals, paired by the dual bases:
$$
\{ \phi_g \mid g \in G \} 
\quad\longleftrightarrow\quad 
\{ \psi_g \mid g \in G \},
$$
where each $\psi_g$ map is an indicator function for $g$: $\psi_g(g') = \delta_{g, g'}$ for any $g' \in G$.
